# How to pass parameter from a .properties file to an HTML page

Tags: html, properties-file

Greetings Fellow Stackers,
I have a property file "*demo.properties*" which contains key - value pair:
**Build=47**

I also have an HTML (static) page '*demo.html*'

```
<html>
<body>
The current build is:  <!--here I want the value of build from the demo.properties -->
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to access the value the '**Build**' value here? Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to read your file and then split the text read from demo.properties file on "=" just to get the build version.

```
var readFile = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var result = reader.result;
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
    outputDiv.innerText = "The current build is: " + result.split("=")[1];
  };
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```

Working plnkr is: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4ElxZSPIbzwIdZDQ6Xnk?p=preview)